# Connect to LinkedIn using Java and OAuth

Tags: java, linkedin-api

I used the below code:

```
    String linkedinKey = "";    //add your LinkedIn key
    String linkedinSecret = ""; //add your LinkedIn Secret

    LinkedInOAuthService oauthService;
    LinkedInRequestToken requestToken;

    System.out.println("Fetching request token from LinkedIn...");  
    String authUrl = null;
    String authToken,authTokenSecret;

    oauthService= LinkedInOAuthServiceFactory.getInstance().createLinkedInOAuthService("",""); 
    requestToken= oauthService.getOAuthRequestToken();
    authToken= requestToken.getToken();  
    authTokenSecret = requestToken.getTokenSecret();  

    System.out.println("Request token " +requestToken);
```

But after executing it i get an error as:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: oauth.signpost.OAuthProvider.retrieveRequestToken(Loauth/signpost/OAuthConsumer;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthServiceImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(LinkedInOAuthServiceImpl.java:148)

I used signpost-core-1.2.1.2 and linkedin-j jar files.

Please help me out where i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have downloaded different jars. Rebuild your project with jars from https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/linkedin-j/linkedin-j-1.0.429-binary.zip link (search for inkedin-j-1.0.429-binary.zip or latest version if the link is not working). Hope this helps.

Comment: Worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't actually set your key and secret to empty strings did you?

`String linkedinKey = "";    //add your LinkedIn key
String linkedinSecret = ""; //add your LinkedIn Secret`

Comment: No it's not empty string i already set the LinkedIn  key and secret.